# JasperReports as a generic document generation tool

Tags: java, jasper-reports, document, report

I need some input if this is possible.

I guess most of you who have used JasperReports use it to - obviously - generate reports.

My question is, can you use it to generate generic documents? Ergo, documents that AREN'T reports. Say, for example, an automated letter of authority with fields you can just populate at run time. Or a company form that is filled up by your app then generates a pdf using JasperReports.

The only other solution that came up was iText, which I believe is far more capable of achieving the desired output.

Any inputs would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, but I wouldn't--IMO you're better off using raw iText, or one of the dynamic languge PDF generators. IIRC iText can fill in PDF forms, too, so if you have someone else creating the PDFs, they can just be populated via iText.

OTOH, if they're relatively simple, it probably doesn't matter very much--you can pass non-tabular data to JR, I'm just not sure it's any easier that way.

Comment: I would say it isn't a simple document. It's a very elaborate, albeit, flashy brochure for a client. There are rows in it though that are dynamic but not on all parts of the document. Those rows are, in fact, a multi-level list of items. A dynamically generated list of clauses. At first glance, one would think these parts can be done with Jasper but all the fancy stuff on the brochure takes all of that possibility away from using Jasper.

Comment: @ChadM. I'm not sure what fancy stuff takes it away from Jasper; you can do some pretty sick stuff with it. If you're patient. IMO it sounds more like a PDF that should have stuff filled in by code, though, particularly if it's being created as a template in an actual PDF tool.

Comment: @ChadM. I thought you meant like graphical elements and the like, which have been my biggest pain point. I don't know; you can generate a bunch of different types of things with JR; whether or not it makes sense in your case, can't tell.

Comment: Okay, for illustrative purposes it should look something like this:

    `Thank you for purchasing our product Mr. {yourname}  
  
    You have availed of the following items:  
    1) room for two at hotel  
    2) free transportation from hotel to airport  
    3) guided tours  
       * inclusive of meals  
       * no dinner covered  `

items 1-3 are dynamic. and so are the bullets under 3.

when I said "fancy" stuff, i meant embedded images, colored beveled corners and whatnot.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to edit my comment. Still new to this forum. Yes graphical stuff, you are correct.

Comment: @ChadM. Like I said, you can do some pretty twisted stuff with JR alone, without mucking around with direct PDF access.

Comment: I guess so, but I've been at this for weeks and I haven't found a single working example of anything resembling what my client wants.  
The closest thing that has at least all the elements like the brochure is an iText sample calendar I found in their tutorials.

Comment: So basically, using iReport is much more practical in this scenario than raw PDF? But just for clarification, why'd you initially say I'm "better off using raw iText"?

Comment: @Chad Originally it sounded like you had pre-canned PDF forms that could just be filled out and had complicated games to play on the code side when determining content.

Comment: Nope, pdf is built at run time. ATM, through a jasper file. Thanks.

Comment: I know this is a little late but after fooling with iReports for a month I've given up working on it. I found that I built my module a lot faster (roughly a week or two) using iText so thank you for this insight. :)

Answer (score 2):

I do all kinds of elaborate reports with [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport). It is an amazing designer for JasperReports. It allows to drag and drop components and connect to your DB or JavaBean Datasources with wizards. A very mature application that gives you all sorts of report exporting capabilities.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but the thing here is what I'm generating is not a report, it's a brochure.

But let's just say it's possible like you said, I have observed that Jasper mostly reads a list of beans, but what if the datasource I'm using is not a list but a bean itself?

Comment: @ChadM. Doesn't matter--you can pass arbitrary information to a report (although I'd have to look up syntax etc.)

Comment: Well that would be great! So far the closest thing that at least resembled what my client wants in terms of aesthetic items is the calendar example on an iText tutorial. Nothing in jasper.

Comment: Beans have accessors. iReport allows you to use a JavaDatasource instead of a DB in your report. Here is an example http://i-proving.ca/space/Technologies/JasperReports/Using+the+Bean+Collection+Datasource

Comment: Ok, this sort of gives me an idea. The existing code I'm working on has this. One last thing though, does jasper support hashmap as field classes? Because I get this error: The constructor JRBeanCollectionDataSource(HashMap) is undefined

Comment: It takes "java.util.Collection<?>" as argument: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html

Comment: Okay, my bad, i was explicitly saying use Hashmap when I should've set it to Collection. Don't know if linkedhashmaps will work effectively though. Thanks.

Comment: According to Bruce Eckel: "LinkedHashMap tends to be slower than HashMap for insertions because it maintains the linked list (to preserve insertion order) in addition to the hashed data structure. Because of this list, iteration is faster.". For extractions no delay...

Comment: @Costis Aivalis. Yes, I understand the consequences. And like it says, it preserves insertion order, and this is currently what we want.

Comment: Okay, this didn't work. I have a LinkedHashMap (field myMap as java.util.Collection) as the data source that I passed to a subreport new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{myMap}) but it tells me error parsing value.

I tried removing the new JRBeanCollectionDataSource as per another article (solved by Dave Newton ,coincidentally) but still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

With iText you can do anything. But it is a programming API and so you either have to create your own design tool or construct the reports in code. For something simple or that will rarely change, it works well.

If you want a full-blown docgen solution, you need a product like Document Science, Thunderhead, or [Windward Docgen](http://www.windward.net/document-generation.php) (disclaimer, I'm the CTO at Windward). The beauty of these solutions is you design templates (in the case of Windward you design in Word) that are then passed to the system so it does not require programming to create/revise a document. And they output to pretty much any format.